# Let $f(x) = \arctan x + \mathop{\text{arccot}} x$. Find $f(0) + f(1) + f(\sqrt{2}) + f(\sqrt{3})$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x) = \arctan x + \mathop{\text{arccot}} x$. Find $f(0) + f(1) + f(\sqrt{2}) + f(\sqrt{3})$.

This is what i got,

$$\left(0+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

Comment: I take it those are the first two terms $f(0)$ and $f(1)$. Hmm ... something interesting there: they both equal $\pi/2$. I wonder if $f(x)$ for arbitrary $x$ follows such a pattern....

Comment: You can construct an angle of given tangent x with a right triangle of legs x and 1.

Comment: should not each one of them be  $\pi/2,$  so totals $2\pi$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Consider this image:

[image]

We know that $\tan \theta = x$, so $\theta = \arctan x$. What is the other angle, as a function of (a) $\theta$ and (b) $x$ ?

Answer (score 0):

$\arctan x+ \operatorname{arccot} x =\frac\pi2$